# Why does Corda 3.1 require a Jetty server dependency

Tags: corda

I am building a Springboot restful API to communicate with my Corda V3.1 node.

What I find is that it requires a Jetty dependency whereas Corda V2.0 did not. Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the Jetty dependency is only there for the webserver component, see https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/master/webserver/build.gradle

If you are creating a REST API yourself, you do not need the **corda-webserver** component at all.